# Videos.js <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script> in the head of page or after each video?

Tags: video.js

Newbie video.js question here.

I manage to get the video.js player to work fine two different ways.

1. By putting the

   ```
   <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script>
   ```

in the head of my page,and using the video tag:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
<p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a 
href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
```

2. By putting the

   ```
   <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script>
   ```

right after each video tag, without putting it in the head of my page:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
<source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a 
href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
     <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script>
```

Is there a way which is preferable?

I am also using the video.js resolution-switcher plugin, and I got it to work both ways as well.

1. By putting the

   ```
   <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script>
   <script src="videojs-resolution-switcher/lib/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"></script>
   ```

   in the head of my page, and using the video.js video tag plus the resolution-switcher plugin ref:

   ```
   <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
   poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
   data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
   <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
   <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
   <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
   <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a 
   href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
   <script>videojs('example_video_1').videoJsResolutionSwitcher()</script>
   ```
2. By putting the

   ```
   <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script> 
   <script src="videojs-resolution-switcher/lib/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"></script>
   <script>videojs('example_video_1').videoJsResolutionSwitcher()</script>
   ```

   right after each video tag, without putting the scripts in the head of my page.

   ```
   <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
   poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
   data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
   <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
   <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
   <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
   <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a 
   href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
   <script src="video-js-5.4.4/video.js"></script>
   <script src="videojs-resolution-switcher/lib/videojs-resolution-switcher.js"></script>
   <script>videojs('example_video_1').videoJsResolutionSwitcher()</script>
   ```

Before I duplicate this code over all my other pages I would like to know what is best.

Also, I notice that the setup info says to link to the "video.min.js" file instead of the "video.js" file.
Again, does it make a difference?

Thank you for any expert help.

Jean

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter, but you should include the script once, not after *each* video tag. However if you also use the IE8 shim, that script does need to be in the head.

video.min.js is minified so is less data to transfer. You can use this in production. video.js is useful when you want to debug the code. The same goes for the CSS files.

Comment: Should I also use the video-js.min.css instead of the video-js.css file?

Everything seems to work fine on Chrome, IE 11 and Firefox, even with the resolution-switcher plugin. In the pages updated with the resolution-switcher plugin, when using Safari on the iPad, I get only audio playback when the videos are minimized, if I go full screen then the video works, go figure... Here is the site:[link] (http://violinnotebook.com) So far, I installed the resolution-switcher plugin on the Home page, and the [link](http://violinnotebook.com/suzVln/suzVln_1.13.html) page.